# WooCommerce shop page white space under product image

Tags: woocommerce, removing-whitespace

I have a WooCommerce shop page.

I may lack a knowledge to fix this which could be an easy fix but please help me to eliminate the white space under product image in WooCommerce page:
here is the link:

https://sonopoint.com/shop/

Thank you very much.

I tried different online-resources none of them helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your page builder, Fusion Builder, is adding a container for details about the product, styled as CSS class "product-details-container".  Remove this container, and you should loose this white space.

Comment: hi. thanks for help but i even do not know where to got which page to open and where is that CSS to eliminate.

Comment: Before you do anything in CSS, try to fix it in your page builder.